# JS conditional: Run script if not at home page

Tags: javascript

Could some kind soul provide a bit of code?

I know just enough JS to crash my site. I am currently running a script provided by Google to display related content. I am manually adding the code to the bottom of each page.

I want to add the code to the template but I do not want it to run on the home page so that it doesn't display at the end of each teaser. Here is what I am working with. From here I am clueless!

```
<h3>Related Content:</h3><br /><br />
<script async='async' src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Matched Content -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-9296841369954395"
 data-ad-slot="6081148663"
 data-ad-format="autorelaxed"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to write your website? Is it just JavaScript and html files? Or is it in some kind of framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the contents of the script in an if statement checking to see you the current page is the homepage and then appending the script.

```
<script>
    if ( window.location.pathname !== "/" ) {
        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.type = "text/javascript";
        newScript.setAttribute("async", "true");
        newScript.setAttribute("src", "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
        document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(newScript);
    }
</script>
```

Not sure if you want the below code to be excluded from running on the homepage or by stopping the script from loading will disable the tag from communicating with Google. We can change the code if so.

```
<!-- Matched Content -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-9296841369954395"
 data-ad-slot="6081148663"
 data-ad-format="autorelaxed"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```